# Access first name and last name from user_register

Tags: plugin-development

does anyone know how to grab first_name and last_name from $user_id for passing into a function firing on the hook user_register?

I am having no luck with either:

```
function random_name ($user_id){    

$new_user = get_userdata($user_id);
$user_email = $new_user -> user_email;

// get all the meta data of the newly registered user
$new_user_data = get_user_meta($user_id);

// get the first name of the user as a string
$user_firstname = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );

// get the last name of the user as a string
$user_lastname = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', true );

echo $user_firstname . $user_lastname . $user_email;
```

}

I am trying to retrieve the valuesof first name and last name so that I can pass them into an API POST for populating an entery on an external API but when  compile the API POST all I get through is the email address?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The Codex is always a good place to look for things. Check out this https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user

Where you will find this sample code:

```
<?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    /**
     * @example Safe usage:
     * $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     * if ( ! $current_user->exists() ) {
     *     return;
     * }
     */
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
```

Which uses the WP_User object: see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User .

Comment: Is wp_get_current_user not for checking who is logged in? I am trying to get the first and last name from a newly registered user. I checked the codex for user_register and WP_user object but couldn't see it. Thank you for the comment @Rick Hellewell

Comment: If you know the user id, you can pass that as a parameter for wp_get_current_user. Otherwise defaults to current user.